# Coin transport chain game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose we have a line of 2013 banks that ends with a vault. The bank nearest to the vault has 1 sack of money, the bank second nearest has 2 sacks. The bank farthest away has 2013 sacks.

Jerry corporation and Meyer corporation are hired to take the sacks of money to the vault. In each turn a player can select a bank and take a positive integer number of sacks to the next bank (or directly to the vault if he chose the bank next to the vault). The winner is the company that makes the move that leaves all bags in the vault.

Which player has a winning strategy? Which is the strategy? Can we generalize to $n$ banks?

Comment: Why did you post this as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755036/game-with-a-line-of-bins and then delete it and then post it again?

Comment: Because yolo swag. No because I accidentaly typed it wrong the first time and that caused it not to get points.

Comment: So, why didn't you just edit it?

Comment: I did, but it didn't receive attention. Now it did.

Comment: Shooting up a movie theater also receives attention. More justification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:  this is an impartial game, so must be [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).  Each bank is a nim heap.  The first bank is clearly a heap of the number of bags in it.  Even numbered banks don't matter, as the second player can mirror the first player's actions, moving each bag down two positions and ending in the vault.

Comment: So how can I work out who wins?

Comment: You need to equate each bank to a Nim heap. The problem is to find the size. I gave some big hints, particularly the one about the even banks being zero. Then Nim add them, which is bit wise XOR. If you get zero the second player wins

Comment: I suppose it goes without saying that you will have to read up on Nim to take full advantage of Ross' answer & comment. But Ross has given you a link, so you should be OK on that. Once you've done that, you can post a complete answer, if you like.

Comment: I could just tell you the winner.  Otherwise I would have to write a whole treatise on Nim, which already exist.  The [Sprague-Grundy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) is central to the analysis.  There is a nice discussion of this and much more in [Winning Ways](http://www.amazon.com/Winning-Ways-Your-Mathematical-Plays/dp/1568811306)-a fabulous book.